# is there a way to train a ML model on multiple laptops?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, distributed-training

I have two laptops and want to use both for the DL model training. I don't have any experience in distributed systems and want to know is it possible to use the processing power of two laptops together to train a single model. What about `tf.distribute.experimental.ParameterServerStrategy`? Will it be of any use?

Comment: Check the docs here https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training

Comment: It doesn't say how to combine two machines to use the processing power of both.

Comment: I think Model Parallelism is what you are looking for. Please refer this talk on **Mesh Tensorflow**, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgGyWS40g-g&list=PL6LsUGheZdT8te2nsOnFpzDQ2Am19VCYd&index=263. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use multiple devices for training your model and you need to have cluster and worker configuration to be done on both the devices like below.

```
tf_config = {
    'cluster': {
        'worker': ['localhost:12345', 'localhost:23456']
    },
    'task': {'type': 'worker', 'index': 0}
}
```

This [Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/multi_worker_with_keras) from Tensorflow on **Multi-worker training with Keras** will show you all the details about the configuration and training your model.

Hope this answers your question.